# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2322118 into shape (60000,784)

Tags: python, numpy, mnist

I am working on an image classifier that uses Random forest algorithm to classify handwritten mnist digits. I am using code I pulled from github. When I run the code I am always getting an error that says:

File ".\MNIST.py", line 52, in 
X = X.reshape((60000,28*28))
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2322118 into shape (60000,784)

Can someone help me please, I have checked similar questions on stackoverflow but none seem to work for me.

```
# coding: utf-8

# # MNIST dataset classification

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import os
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
from sklearn.externals import joblib

np.random.seed(42)

# ## Fetching the data

 os.system('wget http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz')
 os.system('wget http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz')
 os.system('wget http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz')
 os.system('wget http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz')
os.system('gunzip *.gz')


# ## Loading the data to Numpy arrays


with open("train-images.idx3-ubyte", "rb") as f:
    X = np.frombuffer(f.read(), dtype=np.uint8, offset=16).copy()
    X = np.array(X)
    X = X.reshape((60000,28*28))
```

Comment: maybe because 60000 multiplied by 784 is not equal to 2322118 :|

Comment: You also have an indentation error in those `os.system` calls, which is probably due to copy&paste.

Comment: try np.asarray() in place of np.array().

Comment: @Saurav Panda I have tried your suggestion still no luck

Comment: See, I tried your code with one change, it worked fine in both python 2.7 and 3.5. See you are downloading "train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz", but in file open you are reading train-images.idx3-ubyte.gz, somehow in your file open, - is replaced by .

Comment: Try to edit it.